# How to get the intersection of two arrays in MongoDB ($setIntersection does not work well)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a simple data structure that defines people and their friends.

```
{
  id: 0,
  name: 'a',
  friends: [1,2,3]
}
```

I need to find the common friends of two people. I managed to use the aggregation pipleline get the *friends* array into an array.

```
{ "_id" : 0, "friends" : [ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ] ] }
```

So the *friends* field is a nested array, and I want to get the intersection of its elements.

I tried to use the `$setIntersection` operation, however I found it does not accept a variable of an array, it only accepts an array of variables. So I have to use something like this to get the result.

```
{
  $project: {
    commonFriendIds: {
      $setIntersection: [
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$friends", 0] },
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$friends", 1] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It looks ugly, and I have to modify the code to if I need to get the common friends of 3 or more people.

Is there's a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`$reduce`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) aggregation operator. Now It will provide you the intersection for all the nested arrays inside the `friends` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "commonFriendIds": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$friends",
        "initialValue": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$friends", 0] },
        "in": { "$setIntersection": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HbQvUUsVKlg)

Comment: A brilliant way to set the `initialValue`. Thanks! :)